# How to make paypal transaction detail page link programmatically

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal classic API and fetching all transactions from PayPal. Now I want to redirect user to PayPal Transaction detail page on click of specific transaction. Following link, I have made but neither is working.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=transaction-id-here

https://www.paypal.com/bg/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-recurring-payments&encrypted_profile_id=transaction-id-here&PimpHistoryType=15&return_to=my_accounts_page

https://www.paypal.com/vst/id=transaction-id-here

Is there any way that i can make PayPal transaction detail page link? so that user can view transaction detail on his/her PayPal account.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, PayPal provides no supported way to do this. In general, PayPal does not like to provide (and especially does not like other people to be able to provide) direct links into specific PayPal pages, because these links can be emulated (or wrapped) to provide opportunities for phishing attacks. Note that even PayPal's transaction receipt emails do not include a direct link back to the transaction. PayPal wants to train users to go to www.paypal.comm, login in, then take action.

You could visit a transaction details page yourself and look at the URL and see if you can hack it... but it probably will not work (because the transaction ID is likely not in the URL), and even if you did this your solution could break at any time if PayPal changed their page or URL scheme. Not advised.

Answer (score 0):

As @geewiz mentioned, what you're asking isn't directly available.

What you could do, though, is use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to pull data for a transaction and build your own display page using that data.  This would assume that you're providing links for people see details about transactions they've purchased from you.  You would build the call with your own API credentials using the transaction ID you got back from the original transaction.

Comment: I am using GetTransactionDetails but in case of canceled transactions, I am not getting much details(important one) that is why we are sending user to Paypal transaction detail page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If a transaction is canceled then there is no transaction details page because there is no transaction.  What is it that you are referring to?

Comment: But there should be identity that which transaction has canceled. Currently I am not getting any identification.

Comment: PayPal doesn't send anything about a canceled transaction.  You could build your own notification or database update into your CancelURL, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to payment detail page with transaction Id *(Your user must be logged in paypal as you know)* like below;

**For Sandbox;**

```
<a href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=YOURTRANSACTIONID">Show Details</a>
```

**For Live;**

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=YOURTRANSACTIONID">Show Details</a>
```

But i would not recommend, this links wont if paypal change url scheme.